# Angular and rxjs subect for state management

Tags: angular, rxjs

I just wonder if this is okay to use Subject in a service to notify component that state was changed. Let me give an example.
E.g. I have one component adresses-list.component.ts
it is just a list of adresses. When definite address is clicked, its full info will be opoened to right side of the list or in the modal. It
will be called "edit-address.component.ts"
So in this component user can edit address and save changes.
Of course I understand, that there will be a request to backend to update it.
However, the problem is that my adresses-list.component.ts won't know about this changes because it is subscribed to addressses observable and not on the changes.
So my question:
Is it a normal practice to do the following 
in my service.ts:

```
addressesUpdated = new Subject();
editAddressById(id) {
// send info to DB
  return this.http.patch().map(_ => {this.addressesUpdated.next())
}
```

In my addresses-list.component.ts

```
service.addressesUpdated.switchMap( _ => service.getAddresses())
.subscribe(...save data here)
```

It seems to me that there is a better solution and more elagant one but I don't know how to do it better)

Comment: yeah that's totally fine.

Comment: Though you could certainly use redux, ngrx, or some other state manager, if you use injector scopes and observables properly, state management with angular out-of-the-box is sufficient.

Comment: Just a note: you should generally avoid having your `Subject` public but rather return its observable part: `service.addressesUpdated.asObservable()` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can certainly do it. Angular's `EventEmitter` is also just a subject underneath (https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). However, if you feel you need to do this more often I would recommend looking at a state management solution like ngrx store: https://github.com/ngrx/platform

Comment: Professionally and personally, I've never had a good experience with ngrx. It was overkill, lots of boilerplate code, doesn't scale well, and really boiled down to poor data architecture---just my opinion.

Comment: For me it's worked really well, but you are right, very often it's an overkill and it is very hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular way to do it would be two-way model binding with an @Output EventEmitter. Is your child component for editing addresses getting its viewmodel from a attr binding on a selector tag? If so, you're half way there. This is how I would implement what you want to achieve.

### Models

```
export class AddressModel {
    public Street1: string;
    public Street2: string;
    public City: string;
    public StateProvince: string;
    public PostalCode: string;
    public CountryCode: string;
}

export class ApiResponse {
    public Success: boolean;
    public ErrorMessage: string;
}
```

### Parent Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'addressListComponent',
    templateUrl: './addressList.html';
})

export class AddressListComponent implements OnInit {
    addressList: AddressModel[];
    addressSelected: boolean[];

    constructor(private api: AddressApi){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.AddressList = new AddressList();
        this.api.GetAddressList()
            .then(response: AddressModel[] => {
                this.addressList = response.slice(0);
                this.addressList.forEach(addr => {
                    this.addressSelected.push(false);
                });
            });
    }
}
```

### Parent View

```
<div class="card" *NgFor="let address of addressList; let i = "index"; [attr.data-index]="i" (click)="addressSelected[i]=!addressSelected[i]">
    <div class="card-body">
        <label>{{address.Street1}}</label>
        <label>{{address.Street2}}</label>
        <label>{{address.City}}</label>
        <label>{{address.StateProvince}}</label>
        <label>{{address.PostalCode}}</label>
        <label>{{address.Country}}</label>
    </div>
    <editAddressComponent *ngIf="addressSelected[i]" [(addressModel)]="addressList[i]"></editAddressComponent>
</div>
```

### Edit Address Child Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'editAddressComponent',
    templateUrl: './editAddress.html'
})

export class EditAddressComponent {
    @Input() addressModel: AddressModel;
    @Output() addressModelChanged: EventEmitter<AddressModel> = new EventEmitter<AddressModel>();

    constructor(private api: AddressApi) { }

    saveChanges(): void {
        this.api.saveAddressChanges(this.addressModel)
            .then(response: ApiResponse => {
                if (response.Success === true) {
                    this.addressModelChanged.emit(this.addressModel);
                } else {
                    alert(response.ErrorMessage);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

### Child Edit Address View

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <input [(ngModel)]="addressModel.Street1"/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="addressModel.Street2"/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="addressModel.City"/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="addressModel.StateProvince"/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="addressModel.PostalCode"/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="addressModel.Country"/>
        <button (click)="saveChanges()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `[()]` syntax on the parent view. This is where the magic happens. When you have a custom @Input attr on a component and pass it a value via `[]` that's one way binding.

If you wrap the custom attribute in `[()]` like I did with `addressModel` it's short hand for

```
<editAddressComponent [addressModel]="addressList[i]" (addressModelChanged)="addressList[i] = $event;"></editAddressComponent>
```

What this means is, behind the scenes Angular is setting your child component up to support a event emitter, that's what the `()` template syntax represents.

Take

```
<button (click)="doStuff();"></button>
```

for example.

The `()` denotes an eventEmitter, and you're assigning to it, what to do when it is emitted, in this case, execute the doStuff() method.

So by using

```
<editAddressComponent [(addressModel)]="addressList[i]"></editAddressComponent>
```

You are setting up the child component to support an EventEmitter, now you just need to make one.

That's what `@Output` is doing. It's registering a useable variable in your child component to be of type `EventEmitter` that specifically emits a `AddressModel` object.

Now when the user saves their changes, if the changes were saved successfully you are using the EventEmitter to emit an event passing the changed addressModel as the object to be captured.

Then in your parent component you are capturing the object, and assigning it to your addressList at index i. This will keep your parent component view in sync with the changes made by your child component.